# Android - Showing a crosshair in the center of my Google Map

Tags: android, dictionary, center

I have an app with a Google Map and a ItemizedOverlay used to show some markers (From the MapView official tutorial). I need your help with this: I want to show a crosshair always on top and centered on the map, even when the map is panned.

I have read this topic: [Creating a Crosshair in the Center of My Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151218/android-creating-a-crosshair-in-the-center-of-my-google-map) but there is no explanation on how to use the code answered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Copy either of the `Overlay` classes from that answer into your project.

Step #2: Add an instance of that `Overlay` class to your `MapView` via `getOverlays().add()`, just like you are adding your own `ItemizedOverlay`.

Step #3: There is no step #3.

This assumes that their sample code works, and I have not tried it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think using Overlay class is not suitable for google map api v2 + . I am developing google map application and want to show a crosshair at center such that when ever user clicks a button the marker is placed at center. So please if you can help me with how to do this in google map v 2 or v3

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria: This question was from early 2012, before Maps V2 existed. I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain what you are trying to accomplish and seek assistance.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have raised a separate question at SO . Link to question is :- http://stackoverflow.com/q/39488157/5309039 Please go through this and if you can help me it would be great help. Thanks