# Android Google Map V2 Draw a crosshair in center of map screen

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay, android-googleapiclient

I am developing an android application using google maps. I want to show a crosshair in center of screen and then would like to plot marker at center when user clicks button. So my question is how to draw a cross hair on maps.

I searched for this but all soultions points to old google map api where using Overlay class (com.google.android.maps) crosshair is obtained , but now there is no support for this class.

Please help

I want to acheive this thing:-

[image: Cross Hair]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been using relative layouts to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/crosshair"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```